# Как в Lampp перенести файл вне htdocs?

Tags: linux, permissions, copy, lampp

Сильно начинающий.
Мне нужно сохраненные в lampp/htdocs/myfolder файлы скопировать в /home/user/otherfolder
"copy" ожидаемо выдает ошибку доступа. Какие есть варианты ?

Comment: Может быть мягкую ссылку сделать ?

Comment: Нет подробностей. А раз так, то попробуйте копировать, используя sudo

Comment: Подробнее: Реализую систему для проведения тестов программно- аппаратного комплекса. Есть список тестов, при выполнении которых нужно переместить соответствующий выбранному тесту файл с тестовыми данными из некоторой папки-хранилища во входную папку, которую читает комплекс. Текстовый файл 140 байт переносится корректно, а бинарный файл 100 кб уже пишет про ограничение доступа. Удаленная папка одна и та же. Не получается в нее даже file_put создать файл.

Comment: `sudo` + `rsync`?

Answer (score 0):

Копировать процессом, у которого есть доступ. Например, по расписанию. См. `cron`.